# Why doesn't the function in my while loop use the updated variable value

Tags: python, while-loop

So I'm taking a beginner Python class and one of my questions is to write code that takes `n` number (e.g. 5) and asks the user to enter n-1 numbers in n and finds the missing number. I can't use anything more advanced than loops.

For some reason even though the value of `nn` gets updated ever time the loop runs the value of `number` only decreases by 1 every time the loop runs.

```
n = int(input('Please enter n: '))
ntotal = int(n*(n+1)/2)
print ('Please enter n: ')

print (ntotal)
i = 0
k = i
while i != n-1:
    nn = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    number = ntotal - nn
    print (nn)
    i += 1

print (number)
```

Comment: You assign to "number" in each loop iteration but you only use last value.

Comment: you should use `ntotal = ntotal - nn` and at the end use `print(ntotal)`

Comment: Your code seems to do more than what you described and it's confusing. What is `ntotal` supposed to be? Why `print('Please enter n: ')`? Also `k` is unused. Please make a [mre].

Comment: Also are you not allowed to use `range`? BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Oh I just realized `ntotal == sum(range(n+1))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `ntotal`

```
    ntotal = total - number
```

or shorter

```
    ntotal -= number
```

and display `ntotal` at the end

---

```
n = int(input('Please enter n: '))
ntotal = int(n*(n+1)/2)

#print('ntotal:', ntotal)

i = 0
while i != n-1:
#for _ in range(n-1):
    number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    ntotal -= number
    #print('number:', number, 'ntotal:', ntotal)
    i += 1

print(ntotal)
```